# EXCEL 2013 Condtional Formatting Issue

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements

I have data in one workbook, data in sheet 1 and sheet 2.
I would like to know how to have the data highlighted in sheet 1 if it is available in sheet 2.

I have tried a couple of things, but not lucky yet.

Hope someone can help.
Was using MATCH and ISNUMBER, but these didn't seem to work.

-Daniel

Comment: Please be more specific in your description and give a little example on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Two tabs in an excel file.... we have a list of 500 parts on sheet2, multiple parts on sheet1, but also different parts, I need to highlight the parts in sheet1 which are also in sheet2 using conditional formatting. I can send an example per mail as well.

Comment: you should post a MCVE( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here. Another question that arises is :are the possible matches in the same row? Or do you just have two (unordered) lists and want to see the elements which are the same in both lists.

Comment: One list (column) with part numbers needs to be compared with a different one and if the part number is in the other list (column), needs to be highlighted yellow, also if we add additional part numbers which can be recurring, if they fall under the requirement, also need to be yellow. Do you have an email address then I can send you an example of the list I mean.

Comment: As I said build a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and post it here. in your case just 2 small lists of words and what should happen. Add this to your question and then people can get their head around your problem. I won't tell you my email address (partly because I'm paranoid about these things). But also this is a site where problems are posted and solved for EVERYONE to see. not just the ones that have your file. And by writing an MCVE you may get more insight on your problem aswell.